# Grails/Gorm - namedQuery hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have the following domain classes

```
class EventA {
   static belongsTo = [offer: Offer]
}
class EventB extends EventA {}
class EventC extends EventA {}

class Offer {
 static hasMany [events: EventA]
}
```

I need to retrieve offers that are not associated with an `EventC`.

In SQL this can easily be performed as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OFFER O
  LEFT JOIN EVENTC C ON O.event_id = C.id
 WHERE C.ID IS NULL
```

Searching through the grails documentation I found [instanceOf](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/instanceOf.html). Stating that once you have the result set you can perform a check of the instance type.

```
    def offers = Offer.list()
    for (Offer o in offers) {
       for(Event e : o.events) {
          if (e.instanceOf(EventC)) {
              // no bueno
          }
       }
    }
```

The above just feels wrong. I would prefer to have the database do such filtering for me. Is there a way to perform such a filter with `searchCriteria`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually ended up being easier then I expected. On my search criteria, I can build an expression to not include any Offer that has an event `EventC`.

Example:

```
Offer.with {
   events {
     ne('class', EventC)
   }
}
```

Since I questioned this approach I enabled hibernate logging. Ironically, it generated SQL that was pretty similar to what I was after.

```
SELECT *
  FROM OFFER O
  LEFT JOIN EVENTB B ON O.ID == B.EVENT_ID
  LEFT JOIN EVENTC C ON O.ID == C.EVENT_ID
 WHERE
 (
  CASE 
      WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
      WHEN C.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 2
    END <> ?
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by querying the `Event` classes directly. That way you can specifically query the flavor of `Event` you care about. Then query the `Offer` table with the list of Id's

```
Offer.findAllByIdInList(EventC.list().offerId)
```

Comment: My only concern with this approach is I only need to remove one of several events. This would require building a list of all ID across all events. In a production database, this would be huge.

Comment: If you know the Offer ID, you could do `EventC.findAllByOfferId(12345).delete()`